# I don't see the subscription option on SSRS developer edition 2019

Tags: subscription, ssrs-2019

I just downloaded a developer edition for SSRS - to practice some sample DBs since I have lost touch with SSRS I configuring everything properly but I don't see the subscription option at all --
Where did i go wrong?

[SSRS subscription page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1riL7.png)

I expected to see the +New Subscription button but I do not see anything to do with subscriptions
All I see is the image I have added
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8I1c.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5IXI.png)